# Pegar ID do URL no lugar da INDEX

Tags: php, url, get

Olá, gostaria de saber como que faz para pegar o ID da URL como se a index fosse a ID, tipo assim
Usando GET:

```
http://domain.com/api.php?id=1999&output=json
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Ok, até ai tudo bem, mais eu gostaria de saber como que faz para pegar o id assim:

```
http://domain.com/1999/api.php?output=json
```

Gostaria de saber como que pega este ID que no caso seria `1999`.

---

Quero que minha *index* detecte desde modo, um ótimo exemplo é a API do PagSeguro, aquele link ou a do Mercado Pago:

```
http[s]://api.mercadopago.com/collections/notifications/{id here}?access_token={token here}
```

Exemplo:

```
http[s]://api.mercadopago.com/collections/notifications/1799030657?access_token=APP_USR-46....
```

A output ficaria mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você alterou a url com o .htaccess, certo?

Comment: Depende do que você está falando amigo, eu alterei mais creio que não seja o que você esteja citando, poderia me dar um exemplo amigo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deve alterar isso no `htaccess`, por exemplo:

**Alterações:**

HTACCESS:

> /public_html/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/api.php?$ api.php?id=$1$2 [QSA]
```

PHP:

> /public_html/api.php

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$output = $_GET['output'];
?>
```

**Explicação:**

O RewriteRule irá "ler a url" mas irá apontar para outro lugar, acredito que assim ficará fácil de entender.

Digitando o URL:

```
http://domain.com/1999/api.php?output=json
```

Irá chamar o aquivo:

```
api.php?id=1999&output=json
```

Isso NÃO IRÁ REDIRECIONAR O USUÁRIO, mas é possível fazer também redirecionando.

**Construção:**

Caso não entenda o RewriteEngine, aqui está um breve passo-a-passo, para saber como isso foi feito, ao menos por mim:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Liga esta função

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/api.php?$ api.php?id=$1$2 [QSA]
#
# Primeira parte:
# ([0-9]+) será o 1999 (http://domain.com/1999)
# /api.php será para restringir (http://domain.com/1999/api.php)
# 
# Segunda parte:
# api.php será o arquivo chamado
# ?id=$1 será o resultado do ([0-9]+) (?id=1999)
# $2 [QSA] será o resto do query/parametros
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `explode('/', $url)`:

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/1999/api.php?output=json'; 
$r = explode('/', $url);
$id = $r[3];
echo $id;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php